# How do you implement recursion for comments?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to parse reddit comments, and I am stuck on how to get all of the comment replies in one call.

A reddit comment object begins with the array `["data"]["children"]`. You loop through that, and then get a `["children"]["replies"]["data"]["children"]` array which gives you all of the sub-comment replies. You can also grab even more comments (if available) from the `["replies"]["data"]["children"]` array.
Right now, I have it hard-coded so that it only retrieves up to three levels deep. How do I make it dynamic so it keeps on retrieving until there are no more comments?

Here is the code I have so far that is not dynamic:

```
    JsonObject data = commentsObj.get("data").asObject(); 

    JsonArray children = data.get("children").asArray(); 

    final TreeNode root = TreeNode.root(); 

    for (int i=0; i < children.size(); i++)
    {
        JsonObject obj = children.get(i).asObject(); 
        JsonObject dataObj = obj.get("data").asObject();            

        String author = fetchWithHandling(dataObj, "author"); 
        String body = fetchWithHandling(dataObj, "body");  
        String likes = fetchWithHandling(dataObj, "likes"); 
        int score = fetchIntWithHandling(dataObj, "score"); 
        String createdUtc = fetchWithHandling(dataObj, "created_utc");

        JsonObject repliesObj = fetchObjWithHandling(dataObj, "replies"); 

        if (author != null && body != null)
        {   
            RedditCommentHolder.RedditItem redditItem = new RedditCommentHolder.RedditItem(author, body, createdUtc, Integer.toString(score), likes, null); 

            TreeNode commentRoot = new TreeNode(redditItem); 

            if (repliesObj != null)
            {
                JsonObject dataRepliesObj = fetchObjWithHandling(repliesObj, "data"); 
                JsonArray moreComments = fetchArrayWithHandling(dataRepliesObj, "children"); 

                for (int a=0; a < moreComments.size(); a++)
                {
                    JsonObject it = moreComments.get(a).asObject();
                    JsonObject dataComments = it.get("data").asObject(); 

                    String newAuthor = fetchWithHandling(dataComments, "author"); 
                    String newBody = fetchWithHandling(dataComments, "body"); 
                    String newLikes = fetchWithHandling(dataComments, "likes"); 
                    String newCreatedUtc = fetchWithHandling(dataComments, "created_utc");
                    int newScore = fetchIntWithHandling(dataComments, "score");

                    JsonObject thirdCommentsData = fetchObjWithHandling(dataComments, "replies"); 

                    if (newAuthor != null && newBody != null)
                    {
                        RedditCommentHolder.RedditItem newRedditItem = new RedditCommentHolder.RedditItem(newAuthor, newBody, newCreatedUtc, Integer.toString(newScore), newLikes, null); 

                        TreeNode subCommentRoot = new TreeNode(newRedditItem); 

                        if (thirdCommentsData != null)
                        {
                            JsonObject thirdData = fetchObjWithHandling(thirdCommentsData, "data");
                            JsonArray thirdChildren = fetchArrayWithHandling(thirdData, "children"); 

                            for (int p=0; p < thirdChildren.size(); p++)
                            {
                                JsonObject thirdIt = thirdChildren.get(p).asObject(); 
                                JsonObject thirdComments = thirdIt.get("data").asObject(); 

                                String thirdAuthor = fetchWithHandling(thirdComments, "author");
                                String thirdBody = fetchWithHandling(thirdComments, "body"); 
                                String thirdLikes = fetchWithHandling(thirdComments, "likes"); 
                                int thirdScore = fetchIntWithHandling(thirdComments, "score");
                                String thirdCreatedUtc = fetchWithHandling(thirdComments, "created_utc");

                                if (thirdAuthor != null && thirdBody != null)
                                {
                                    RedditCommentHolder.RedditItem thirdRedditItem = new RedditCommentHolder.RedditItem(thirdAuthor, thirdBody, thirdCreatedUtc, Integer.toString(thirdScore), thirdLikes, "continue_thread"); 

                                    TreeNode thirdRoot = new TreeNode(thirdRedditItem);
                                    subCommentRoot.addChildren(thirdRoot);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        commentRoot.addChildren(subCommentRoot); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is from an Android project, and the TreeNode variable is just a view I am setting up. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've answered your question in the title - with recursion :)

I'm not going to give you actual code, since it would be mostly reddit (and android) specific and i don't use reddit (and android), but it looks like a regular recursive DFS would be ok.

Java pseudocode:

```
TreeElementClass root = getElementRecursive(data)

TreeElementClass getElementRecursive(JsonObject obj){
    TreeElementClass parent = new TreeElementClass();
    ...some initialization of the parent element...
    for(JsonObject child : obj.get("children").asArray()){
        parent.addChild(getElementRecursive(child))
    }
    return parent;
}
```